# Can you get an iterator over all values of a collection except one and a reference to that element?

Tags: rust

I want to iterate over clients in a `Vec` and process each using a method that is supposed to take all the other clients as an argument as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve. You could simply vec.remove(index) before iterating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such iterator that I'm aware of, but it's not complicated to create your own:

```
struct X<'a, T: 'a> {
    item: &'a T,
    before: &'a [T],
    after: &'a [T],
}

struct AllButOne<'a, T: 'a> {
    slice: &'a [T],
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a, T> AllButOne<'a, T> {
    fn new(slice: &'a [T]) -> Self {
        AllButOne { slice, index: 0 }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for AllButOne<'a, T> {
    type Item = X<'a, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index > self.slice.len() {
            return None;
        }

        let (before, middle) = self.slice.split_at(self.index);
        let (middle, after) = middle.split_at(1);

        self.index += 1;

        Some(X {
            before,
            after,
            item: &middle[0],
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    for x in AllButOne::new(&a) {
        println!("{:?}, {}, {:?}", x.before, x.item, x.after);
    }
}
```

```
[], 1, [2, 3, 4]
[1], 2, [3, 4]
[1, 2], 3, [4]
[1, 2, 3], 4, []
```

This returns two slices, one for all the values before the current item and one for after. You can perform allocation and stick them into the same collection if you need.